# Why do i get a parse error when using the funtion set_pos() in GDscript

Tags: parse-error, godot, gdscript

I keep getting this error for some reason. I dont know why. It tells me there's a problem with that the class does not include the function. The exact error is:

built-in:8 - Parse Error: The method "set_pos" isn't declared in the current class."

Here's the Code:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

func _ready():
    set_process(true)

func _process(delta):
    set_pos(Vector2(100, 100))
```

Answer (score 1):

KinematicBody2D does not have a function called set_pos. I am pretty sure that there is no function called set_pos in Godot at all.

Did you mean to change the position of the object? Its a KinematicBody2D, meaning also Node2D. You can move a Node2D like this:

```
global_position = Vector2(100, 100)
```

or

```
set_global_position(Vector2(100, 100))
```

if you prefer that.

Comment: Yes, `set_pos()` was from Godot versions before 3.0

Answer (score 0):

The older versions of Godot use set_pos function. But in the newer versions (for sure after 3.0) you directly change the property position of the Kinematic Body.